# How to overlay images in a carousel when using the Avada theme in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, carousel, elementor

I am customizing the WordPress site that is built using the Avada theme. I want to put an image or icon over the image in the carousel. Please show me how to do this.

I am new to WordPress, so I would like to know how to do this.